# Set a colormap to fill a bar plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I'm trying to change the default color of the bar plot with a a colormap without success.

The thing is that I don't like the default color sequence. However, I was wondering if there is a way of automatically switching between colors. I try using the `cycle list name` but it only changes the line and doesn't fill the bars. Is there any hope or do I have to set the colors by hand every time in the `\addplot` command?

This is an example of what I have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=\linewidth,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
x tick label style={
/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
ylabel=Population,
enlargelimits=0.05,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar interval=0.7,
cycle list name=color list`enter code here`
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6)
(1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6)
(1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};

\legend{Far,Near,Here,There}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pgfplots' manual page 58 explains how to declare a `bar cycle list` with your preferred colors, so include something like

```
\pgfplotsset{
   /pgfplots/bar  cycle  list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle  list={%
        {orange,fill=orange!30!white,mark=none},%
        {yellow,fill=yellow!30!white,mark=none},%
        {brown!60!black,fill=brown!30!white,mark=none},%
        {green,fill=green!30!white,mark=none},%
     }
   },
}
```

in your document and will obtain

[image]

Comment: you beat me to it :) And your answer shows that there are multiple ways to achieve the goal with TikZ :)

Comment: @Habi, Ignasi: Thanks for the quick reply, so at the end I have to define the colors by hand. Is it possible to use a colormap or something? What I was trying is to avoid the manual definition, because if I have, let say 10 bars, I have to define 10 different colors, and the same if it is changing.

Comment: @adn: It seems that all `cycle lists` in `pgfplots.code.tex` file doesn't include a `fill` declaration, so when you say `cycle list name=exotic` bars are empty. You have some options, first, use Habi's or mine solutions, second fill a bug (or wish) report in [pgfplots](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/) or send a message to pgfplots-users list and third hope that Christian Feuersänger read your question and provide a better solution ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got the idea, why isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [pgfplots-Manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) (page 133) you have to define yourself a color list to use it later.

I've adapted your example (also with a - I think - nice trick with `\usepackage{preview}`), is that what you've intended??

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{%
    {blue,mark=*,fill=green},
    {color=red,mark=square},
    {dashed,mark=o},
    {dotted,mark=+,fill=orange}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    ylabel=Population,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar interval=0.7,
    cycle list name=mylist
    ]
\addplot
    coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6) (1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)};
\addplot
    coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6) (1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
\addplot
    coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6) (1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};
\addplot
    coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6) (1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};

\legend{Far,Near,Here,There}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: Nice answer also. Probably more general than mine. Although its final goal is not the same, I use `standalone` class instead of `preview`. You just need to type `\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}` to obtain same result.