# pgfplots: How to draw boxplot pairs separated in two y axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment, boxplot, statistics

The user [Korijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185364) has posted a nice approach on how to create pairs of `boxplots` which are belonging to each other.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={RMSE},
height=6cm,
ymin=0,ymax=7,
cycle list={{red},{blue}},
boxplot={
        draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
        %
        box extend=0.3
},
x=2cm,
xtick={0,1,2,...,10},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={%
        {dataset 1\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
        {dataset 2\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
        {dataset 3\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
        {dataset 4\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
},
        x tick label style={
                text width=2.5cm,
                align=center
        },
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.764\\
2.938\\
2.075\\
1.493\\
1.285\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.175\\
2.813\\
2.006\\
3.893\\
2.012\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.621\\
3.659\\
6.357\\
2.851\\
1.416\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.280\\
1.482\\
1.787\\
2.326\\
1.795\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.778\\
2.388\\
1.016\\
1.328\\
1.151\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.028\\
1.571\\
4.090\\
3.875\\
1.890\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.405\\
1.188\\
4.330\\
3.665\\
1.439\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.937\\
1.320\\
1.357\\
1.852\\
1.215\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Question:**

As you can see, there is a pair of `boxplots` existent for each dataset (from dataset 1 to dataset 4).

While preserving the `boxplots` of type "disabled" in y-axis 1, how can I draw the `boxplots` of type "enabled" in an additional second y-axis?

I have created the following code to create a second y-axis:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={y-axis 1},
height=6cm,
ymin=0,ymax=7,
cycle list={{red},{blue}},
boxplot={
        draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
        box extend=0.3
},
x=2cm,
xtick={0,1,2,...,10},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={%
    {dataset 1\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 2\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 3\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 4\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
},
        x tick label style={
                text width=2.5cm,
                align=center
        },
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.764\\
2.938\\
2.075\\
1.493\\
1.285\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.175\\
2.813\\
2.006\\
3.893\\
2.012\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.621\\
3.659\\
6.357\\
2.851\\
1.416\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.280\\
1.482\\
1.787\\
2.326\\
1.795\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.778\\
2.388\\
1.016\\
1.328\\
1.151\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.028\\
1.571\\
4.090\\
3.875\\
1.890\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.405\\
1.188\\
4.330\\
3.665\\
1.439\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.937\\
1.320\\
1.357\\
1.852\\
1.215\\
};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={y-axis 2},
height=6cm,
ymin=0,ymax=7,
cycle list={{red},{blue}},
boxplot={
    draw position={1/3 + floor(\plotnumofactualtype/2) + 1/3*mod(\plotnumofactualtype,2)},
    box extend=0.3
},
x=2cm,
xtick={0,1,2,...,10},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={%
    {dataset 1},%
    {dataset 2},%
    {dataset 3},%
    {dataset 4},%
},
x tick label style={
    text width=2.5cm,
    align=center
},
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.764\\
    2.938\\
    2.075\\
    1.493\\
    1.285\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.175\\
    2.813\\
    2.006\\
    3.893\\
    2.012\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.621\\
    3.659\\
    6.357\\
    2.851\\
    1.416\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.280\\
    1.482\\
    1.787\\
    2.326\\
    1.795\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.778\\
    2.388\\
    1.016\\
    1.328\\
    1.151\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.028\\
    1.571\\
    4.090\\
    3.875\\
    1.890\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.405\\
    1.188\\
    4.330\\
    3.665\\
    1.439\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.937\\
    1.320\\
    1.357\\
    1.852\\
    1.215\\
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

- How can I separate the `boxplot` of "enabled" into y-axis 2?
- All ideas and solutions are appreciated, it is not mandatory to reuse the upper code.

Comment: @marmot: Thanks a lot for your reply! I have updated my question to clarify the desired behavior. :-) What do you mean with `name=upper`?

Comment: @marmot: I want to put the `boxplots` of type `disabled` on y-axis 1, but the `boxplots` of type `enabled` on y-axis 2. The reason for this is that `disabled` and `enabled` have different values and therefore different axis scalings, so I can not use both `boxplot` types within the same y-axis.

Comment: @marmot: In the end, both axis will have 4 datasets each. I just copied y-axis 1 including its plots to have the same scaling for y-axis 2 in the MWE. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=left,
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={y-axis 1},
height=6cm,
ymin=0,ymax=7,
cycle list={{red}},
boxplot={
        draw position={0.3 + \plotnumofactualtype},
        box extend=0.3
},
x=2cm,xmax=4.25,xmin=0,
xtick={0,1,2,...,5},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={%
    {dataset 1\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 2\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 3\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
    {dataset 4\\{\tiny disabled enabled}},%
},
        x tick label style={
                text width=2.5cm,
                align=center
        },
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.764\\
2.938\\
2.075\\
1.493\\
1.285\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.175\\
2.813\\
2.006\\
3.893\\
2.012\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1.621\\
3.659\\
6.357\\
2.851\\
1.416\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
2.280\\
1.482\\
1.787\\
2.326\\
1.795\\
};

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
boxplot/draw direction=y,
ylabel={y-axis 2},
height=6cm,
ymin=0,ymax=7,
cycle list={{blue}},
boxplot={
    draw position={0.7 + \plotnumofactualtype},
    box extend=0.3
},
x=2cm,xmax=4.25,xmin=0,
xtick={0,1,2,...,4},
x tick label as interval,
xticklabels={%
    {dataset 1},%
    {dataset 2},%
    {dataset 3},%
    {dataset 4},%
},
x tick label style={
    text width=2.5cm,
    align=center
},
]

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.778\\
    2.388\\
    1.016\\
    1.328\\
    1.151\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.028\\
    1.571\\
    4.090\\
    3.875\\
    1.890\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1.405\\
    1.188\\
    4.330\\
    3.665\\
    1.439\\
};

\addplot
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    2.937\\
    1.320\\
    1.357\\
    1.852\\
    1.215\\
};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]